# package .apk in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 using Mono for Android

Tags: android, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, mono

I'm using Mono for Android and Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2010 and created HelloMonodroid App. App is running fine in Emulator, when Project is configured to DEBUG.
What i want to do now is build/package an .apk file in RELEASE mode. I followed the steps described on: [Preparing Package](http://mono-android.net/index.php?title=Documentation/Guides/Preparing_Package_for_Android_Marketplace&highlight=sign)

But i'm getting following error:

> monodroid : error 1: This version of mandroid.exe does not support static compilation.

I'm using the evaluation/trial version of Mono for Android. Anybody knows what is wrong here? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4):

I'd guess that your version of monodroid doesn't support static compilation.

Or more usefully, since you're using a eval/trial version, it's probably crippled to prevent releases - to evaluate/trial it, you don't need to create a release version.

Comment: This is correct. You cannot build a static version (a version that **does not** use the shared runtime) with the evaluation version. I have already changed the error message for the next release to be a little more descriptive.